# Prefix search and position in document using Trie

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

Interview question that stumped using this particular data structure. I solved it using two Lists but they were looking for a implementation of a Trie. Not too familiar with this data structure. I have the baseline code of creating nodes and inserting in words to the Trie, then returning a true or false if it contains a prefix. How would I implement a feature of not only returning true, but returning the position in the document where the prefix is? So if given this document:

```
Hello, World! Computer Science is a great major if you enjoy the sciences.
```

prefixPosition("science") would return {24,66}
prefixPosition("i") would return {32,49}

I originally achieved this by creating a list splitting the document on " ". Then looping through that List and creating a second list that contains the character position by counting the words in the list, adding 1 char for the split we did (on the space) and storing that. Then doing a loop through the Original list to see if the element start with our prefix, if it does, go back to the character position list and getting it's position.

How would I have some type of linked list to determine the position while using the Trie?

```
class TrieNode {
    private final Map<Character, TrieNode> children = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean endOfWord;

    Map<Character, TrieNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    boolean isEndOfWord() {
        return endOfWord;
    }

    void setEndOfWord(boolean endOfWord) {
        this.endOfWord = endOfWord;
    }
}
```

```
class Trie {
    private TrieNode root;

    Trie() {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    void insert(String word) {
        TrieNode current = root;

        for (char l : word.toCharArray()) {
            current = current.getChildren().computeIfAbsent(l, c -> new TrieNode());
        }
        current.setEndOfWord(true);
    }

    boolean delete(String word) {
        return delete(root, word, 0);
    }

    boolean containsNode(String word) {
        TrieNode current = root;

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            TrieNode node = current.getChildren().get(ch);
            if (node == null) {
                return false;
            }
            current = node;
        }
        return current.isEndOfWord();
    }

    boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }

    private boolean delete(TrieNode current, String word, int index) {
        if (index == word.length()) {
            if (!current.isEndOfWord()) {
                return false;
            }
            current.setEndOfWord(false);
            return current.getChildren().isEmpty();
        }
        char ch = word.charAt(index);
        TrieNode node = current.getChildren().get(ch);
        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean shouldDeleteCurrentNode = delete(node, word, index + 1) && !node.isEndOfWord();

        if (shouldDeleteCurrentNode) {
            current.getChildren().remove(ch);
            return current.getChildren().isEmpty();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean find(String word) {
        TrieNode current = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char ch = word.charAt(i);
            TrieNode node = current.getChildren().get(ch);
            if (node == null) {
                return false;
            }
            current = node;
        }
        return current.isEndOfWord();
    }

    public TrieNode searchNode(String str){
        Map<Character, TrieNode> children = root.getChildren();
        TrieNode t = null;
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if(children.containsKey(c)){
                t = children.get(c);
                children = t.getChildren();
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }

        return t;
    }

    public boolean startsWith(String prefix) {
        if(searchNode(prefix) == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could build a **suffix tree**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Comment: Augment your `TrieNode` to contain an dynamic sized array eg. ArrayList to hold these indices.